# Why do I get the value "result" for this closure?

Tags: javascript, closures, memoization

Let's say I have this code ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2T3cD/)) intended to memoize modules:

```
var chat = {
 // Create this closure to contain the cached modules
 module: function() {
    // Internal module cache.
    var modules = {};
     console.log('in module:', name);  // <---------- "in return: result"     
    // Create a new module reference scaffold or load an
    // existing module.
    return function(name) {
      console.log('in return:', name); // <---------- "in return: derp"
      // If this module has already been created, return it.
      if (modules[name]) {
        return modules[name];
      }

      // Create a module and save it under this name
      return modules[name] = { Views: {} };
    };
  }()
};

chat.module("derp");
```

Nowhere in the code is the phrase "result" even mentioned. Why would it return that value in the first console log?

Also, how does the return function get the value for the `name` parameter when none is specified in the `module: function() {}` declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log('in module:', name);
```

You are logging `name` before you ever declare it.  So it's using [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.name) instead.

Comment: ok then to answer my second question, how does the return function determine what value to use, if none is supplied?

Comment: @Jason: Because of `return function(name)`.  You are making a function that returns a function, and then immediately calling it.  `chat.module` is actually being set to `function(name)` (the returned function).

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.... that makes sense now. how tricky! the part before the return is kind of like a secret little world that exists to aid the return function.

Comment: i work with closures all the time and i'm just now figuring this out. shame on me

Comment: @Jason: Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 2):

```
… = function() {
    // …
    console.log('in module:', name);  // <---------- "in return: result"     
    return function(name) {…};
}();
```

You see, in the scope of that immediately-executed anonymous function expression, there is no variable "`name`". Therefore, the global variable [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.name) will be used - it's value seems to be `"result"` in your case (the jsfiddle target iframe's name) - try the [unwrapped page](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2T3cD/show/light/), it will log an empty string.

Comment: Yes, in jsfiddle the name is `result`. But in a new document, it will be an empty string.

Comment: Yes, `result` is the target iframe of the jsfiddle app

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference... "**result**" in this example, is the name (or better say the ID) of the lower right window (div/iframe) in JsFiddle...

So as @**Rocket** & @**Bergi** already says... you are getting the "window.name"

Comment: yep, got that from their answers.