# Function does not return names from list only "result" or one name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've written a function that is meant to return a name from a particular list based on the gender selected, but at the moment it only returns "result" (strangely enough this only happens on the fiddle I created, on the actual web app I only get one name). How would I rework my function so that it returns 3 different names, instead of what it is doing right now.

**HTML**

```
<div id="names"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    generateTimeline();
}

function generateTimeline() {
    var genderArray = ['male', 'female'];
    var gender = genderArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * genderArray.length)];
    var name = getName(gender);
    $('#names').append(name + "<br>");
}

function getName(gender) {
    if (gender == "male") {
        var maleNamesArray = new Array();
        $.get('http://methuselah90.comoj.com/male-names.dat', function (data) {
            maleNamesArray = data.split('\n');
            name = maleNamesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * maleNamesArray.length)];
        });
    } else if (gender == "female") {
        var femaleNamesArray = new Array();
        $.get('http://methuselah90.comoj.com/female-names.dat', function (data) {
            femaleNamesArray = data.split('\n');
            name = femaleNamesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * femaleNamesArray.length)];
        });
    }
    return name;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/o557ngL3/1/)

Comment: *No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin ... is therefore not allowed access* <- Same origin policy

Comment: @Bergi: Too damn fast xD

Comment: You are getting `"result"` because you haven't declared your `var name` locally, so it [returns the global `window.name`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12165811/1048572)

Comment: I think the issue I am seeing with "result" being returned in jsfiddle specific? Locally I don't have the problem, but I get the same name returned 3 times instead of 3 different names. I think it is down to an issue with scope in my functions, but can't figure out how and where.

Comment: @Bergi - when you say declare the var name locally, what do you mean? Where should I put it?

Comment: You're not getting it, the ajax calls are asynchronous, you're returning `name` before the ajax calls have completed, and as such there's nothing to return. In the Fiddle the issue is that it's a different domain, and you can't get the data at all.

Comment: @adeneo - Sorry, I still don't understand. I've posted my code here http://pastebin.com/6Ummb1ys. Can you please tell me where I am making the mistake and how to fix it? I am now just getting "undefined", so the ajax calls haven't completed, but I can see the correct output in the console.

Comment: I mean `function getName(gender) { var name; …`. Yes, getting `"result"` is jsfiddle-specific, as explained in the linked answer. Usually (and with the local variable) you would get `undefined`, to solve that see the duplicate question.